# $p^2-p+1=P^3$ prove how many $p$, $P$ pairs are there

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Determine  with a proof all prime numbers $p$ such that $p^2-p+1$ is a cube of a prime number.

$19^2-19+1=7^3$

But is it the only $p$?

How should I prove it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think you meant $19$ where you wrote $9.$  Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Equivalent formulation: prove that there are only six integer solutions to $1=3ab^2-a^3-b^3$.

Comment: Let $y = 8p - 4$ and $x = 4P$, the equation becomes a [Mordell curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve) $y^2 = x^3 + n$ for $n = -48$. For any $n$,  the Mordell curve has at most finitely many integer solutions and all solutions for $0 < |n| \le 10000$ has been computed. For $n = -48$, there are only two set of integer solutions $(x,y) = (4,\pm 4)$ and $(28,\pm 148)$ which corresponds to $(P,p) = (1, 0 \text{ or } 1)$ and $(7,19 \text{ or } - 18)$. In short, $(P,p) = (7,19)$ is the only prime solutions.

Comment: @achillehui, that comment should be an answer

Comment: If the cubed variable is the same as the other powers:$$ax^3+bx^2+c^x+d=0$$
suppose we have $$p^3-p^2+p-1=0$$
The cubic formula is $$=\sqrt[3]{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3 }+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)+\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\biggr)^3}}+\sqrt[3]{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3 }+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)-\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\biggr)^3}}-\frac{b}{3a}$$
Let's see what happens if we enter $1$ for all coefficients.

Comment: This problem is 2005 Balkan Mathematical Olympiad, Problem 2. For a solution, see :  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h35935p224998

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will use here: If $a$ and $b$ are positive integers then $$\boxed{a\mid b\implies a\leq b}$$

Rename $q=P$. We can assume that $p\geq 23$ and so $q\geq 8$. We have $$ p(p-1) = (q-1)(q^2+q+1)$$

- If $p\mid q-1$ then $q^2+q+1\mid p-1$. So $p\leq q-1$ and $q^2+q+1\leq p-1$ so we have $$q^2+q+1\leq q-2\implies q^2+3\leq 0$$
  which is impossible.
- If $p\mid q^2+q+1 $ then $q-1\mid p-1$. Let $r=q-1$ then we have: $p\mid r^2+3r+3$ and $r\mid p-1$ (so $\color{red}{r\leq p-1}$) then $$pr\mid r^2p+3pr+3p-r^2-3r-3$$ and thus $$pr\mid r^2+3r+3-3p$$

**Case 1**: $r^2+3r+3>3p$ then $$pr\leq r^2+3r+3-3p \implies p\leq r+{3\over r+3}< r+1\leq p$$
A contradiction.

**Case 2**: $r^2+3r+3<3p$ then $$pr\leq 3p-r^2-3r-3 < 3p \implies r<3$$
A contradiction.

**Case 3**: $r^2+3r+3=3p =q^2+q+1$ then $$p-1 = 3q-3 = 3r$$ and thus we have $$r^2+3r+3 = 9r+3\implies r=6 \implies q=7$$
A contradiction, since $q>7$.

So the only solution is $P=7$ and $p=19$.

---

**Notice** that we didn't use $P$ is prime.

Comment: Hey @Maria Mazur, would you elaborate on Case 1?

Comment: See red.........

Comment: Wow, niceee...+1